# Integral Equations $y(x) = 2 + \int_x^2 \left[ t - ty(t) \right] dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

My equations is:

$$
y(x) = 2 + \int_x^2 \left[ t - ty(t) \right] dt
$$

What I am not understanding is if I take the derivative of both sides I don't understand how my book gets **x-xy** on the right hand side.  To my understanding if I take the derivative of an integral, it is almost like it is "cancelling" it out.  So why wouldn't it be $x-xy(x)$ or $x-yx^2$?

Comment: You should get $y'(x) = -(x-x y(x))$. Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Clearly I am not understanding this.  Can you break it down further.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Let $F(t)$ be the anti-derivative of $f(t)$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \int_x^2 f(t) dt = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ F(2)-F(x)\right] = -f(x).
$$

Comment: how do you get a negative at the end?

Comment: @JamalCrawford.. $$\frac{d}{dx} \left[-F(x)\right] = -f(x)$$

Comment: Can't understand the downvote.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I cannot either. Maybe they thought it was so trivial they did not want me to hint. not sure

Comment: No hints allowed

Comment: @JamalCrawford..: what ??

Comment: Can't understand the downvote for asking a question

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental theorem of calculus says (skipping the assumptions here) that
if $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$, then $F'(x) = f(x)$.

In the above, the lower limit of the integration is the variable, so $F(x) = \int_x^a f(t) dt = - \int_a^x f(t)dt$, so we have
$F'(x) = - f(x)$.

Explicitly, $F(x) = \int_x^2 (t-t y(t)) dt$, so 
$F'(x) = -(x-x y(x))$.

In the question, the right hand side is $2+F(x)$, so the derivative of the
right hand side is $-(x-x y(x))$.